# Best practice for creating new frame names?

Tags: ros, frame, sensor-msgs, best-practices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a simple two-wheeled platform, and I'm trying to publish ultrasonic range data via the standard [range](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Range.html) message type.

This message type requires a header with a frame_id. The sensors are attached to the part of the robot considered the "/base_link" frame. Should I use that as the frame, or should I create separate frames for each sensor to denote each sensor's unique position? If so, how should I name these? Should it be "/base_link/ultrasonic1" or just "/ultrasonic1"?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258384/best-practice-for-creating-new-frame-names?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2017-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The frame IDs for sensors represent the coordinate frame origin for readings from that sensor, and most sensors report readings relative to the center of their transducer or other sensing element. Unless your sensor is mounted at exactly the same position as base_link, you should define a new frame for each sensor.

The frame naming is up to you, but most systems will use names like `/ultrasonic1`.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1